# Leaving work profile for Tasker

Tags: tasker

I'm using Tasker, and maybe I'm just trying too hard, but I can't seem to set up multiple conditions in the way that I want to. Here's what I'm trying to do:

From M - F (8AM - 5PM), set the phone to silent mode... which is pretty easy. After 5PM rolls around though, I want to kick on the GPS/Network location listener.

If I have left the office, then I want to go ahead and switch off the silent profile, and back to normal. If I haven't yet left the office, I'd like the task to sleep for 15 minutes, and then try again (sometimes I work late).

It's the combination of these two separate tasks that I cannot seem to make work together. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: First, you might have problems kicking on GPS without root. Is your device rooted, and if so, what ROM (stock or custom?) are you running? Everything else shouldn't be that hard to do. I could give you a raw skeleton after you provided these details, so you only would be left with the fine-tuning afterwards. PS: I took the liberty for a little re-formatting of your question to make it easier to read -- hope I got it right. If not, feel free to correct it again :)

Comment: Thank you for updating my question, it is a bit more straight-forward now. My phone is rooted. Running a stock JB that's deodexed (GSM Galaxy Nexus)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now with your latest details, a raw approach. As you are on a stock ROM, switching GPS might not work out-of-the-box. In case it doesn't work, take a look at the [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) plugin, which should be able to help out.

I assume your raw concept is: 8am to 5pm is work time, and you want different settings during work hours and after leaving work, considering eventual late-work issues. So this should preferably turn out as a single profile: *At work do...* and *After work switch to...*. So here's what shoud *basically* work:

---

### Profile "Work":

**Condition:**

- Time from 8am Till 5pm

**Task:**

- Audio -> Silent Mode: On

**Exit Task:**

- Misc -> GPS: On (might need to be replaced by *Secure Settings*, see above)

Now we enter a second profile, and you probably do not even need GPS:

### Profile: "AfterWork":

**Condition:**

- State -> Tasker -> Profile Active: "Work" [x] Invert
- State -> Phone -> Cell Near: (Scan your work cells) [x] Invert

**Task:**

- Audio -> Silent Mode: Off

---

So you see you neither need GPS nor the 15min wait loop. At 8am the "Work" Profile gets active, and switches your phone to silent mode. As you do not really need GPS, you can define some dummy Exit Task here (e.g. again switching Silent Mode on), as otherwise Tasker would automatically revert to the "before" mode.

The second profile does not even check conditions before "Work" has completed, as Tasker remembers which Profiles are active. After that, it starts monitoring the surrounding mobile cells -- which are either known by the phone as needed for telephony. If none of the surrounding cells match any of the scanned cells, the attached task is executed and Silent Mode turned off.

But why so complicated? Much easier done like this:

---

### Profile "Work":

**Condition:**

- Cell Near (Scan your work place mobile cells)

**Task:**

- Audio -> Silent Mode: On

---

Done. No matter what time you are at work, your phone will be silent. And no matter whether you leave work early or late, Silent Mode will be switched off.

Comment: Great answer and explanation. If I could accept this twice for the extra rep, I would. Thank you for the help and the concise answer

Comment: That looks like I hit home with it -- glad I could help, anytime again :)

Comment: @RyanInBinary I just discovered one could award bounties to already existing answers, if one feels it earns extra points... xD Honestly: I'm not begging, just mentioning it in case you happen to receive an extra-ordinary answer some day ;)

Answer (score 5):

Although this question is already answered, and accepted, I would like to add to it.

Sounds like what you want is pure location-based profiles.  Tasker is very powerful, but if you are willing to try an alternative, there is [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5rZWJhYi5MbGFtYSJd).  It is roughly the same as tasker, except that almost every action is location-based. It 'learns' a location you want to set up (like home), by scanning the antennae of the mobile network in the immediate area. That is a lot more energy-efficient than using GPS.

For the things you want to set up, Llama will be much simpler to configure.  Let the phone learn the places you want to use in your conditions, and add one or more actions.  E.g. "leave home" -> do "enable bluetooth" "disable wifi".

You won't have to worry about timings, as the profiles only change when you physically, actually move to or from a location.

Give it a try.

PS: I am not affiliated.